# How to change result encoder

Tags: python, celery

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a single task after a `group`:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type GroupResult is not JSON serializable
```

But I'm unable to change the serialization method. This is what I've tried but keep getting the same error:

```
celery = Celery(__name__)

# attempt 1
celery.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'

# attempt 2
celery.conf.update(result_serializer='pickle')
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @zoran119 try having a look at https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/userguide/serialization.html

Comment: Are you trying to pass GroupResult as argument to some other task? - Do not. Instead, pass the ID of the group and instantiate GroupResult with the ID.